Unable to Convert Python Code to Android App in Google Colab Using Buildozer
Error log:
STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,paramiko,requests,json,datetime', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '12.2.5.6-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TRANSPORT = 'ipc'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     CGROUP_MEMORY_EVENTS = '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.events /var/colab/cgroup/jupyter-children/memory.events'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.19.3-1+cuda12.2'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     HOSTNAME = '77c7fbff5fd4'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     COLAB_TPU_1VM = ''
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '12.1.2.141-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_ROOT_URL = 'http://172.28.0.1:8013/'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '12.2.1.4-1'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = '30s'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.9.6.50-1+cuda12.2'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TOKEN = ''
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20240321'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.5.6-1'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_HOST = '172.28.0.12'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '12.2.140-1'
#     COLAB_WARMUP_DEFAULTS = '1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLUMNS = '100'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '12.2.2'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-12-2=12.2.5.6-1'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nsight-compute-12-2=12.2.2-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab_20240404-060114_RC00'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--logtostderr --listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-1nr8i42d5f7ll '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-12-2=12.2.1.4-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_LSP_DIRS = '/datalab/web/pyright/typeshed-fallback/stdlib,/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-12-2'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_PORT = '6000'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '12.2.1.4-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '83'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '12.1.2.141-1'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.9.6.50'
#     SHLVL = '0'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY = '/usr/colab/bin/language_service'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '12.2.2-1'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.9.6.50-1+cuda12.2'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-12-2'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.19.3-1+cuda12.2'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     COLAB_GPU = ''
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_VERSION = '12.2.2-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '12.2.142-1'
#     LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLAB_FILE_HANDLER_ADDR = 'localhost:3453'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     COLAB_DEBUG_ADAPTER_MUX_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.19.3-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     COLAB_BACKEND_VERSION = 'next'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Python Library Imports:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import paramiko

I've undertaken the following steps to address the issue:

Ensured that all required dependencies (kivy, kivymd, paramiko, requests, etc.) are properly installed.
Reviewed the buildozer.spec file to confirm that all necessary dependencies are correctly listed under requirements.
Verified the compatibility of the Python code with the supported version of Python by Buildozer.
Analyzed the full log generated by Buildozer to pinpoint the specific error.

Environment details:
The code is executed within a Google Colab notebook, utilizing the following environment specifications:
[Include any relevant environment details or configurations here]
I kindly request any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.
Additionally, I'm uncertain about how to properly edit the .spec file.
